# How to configurate a View of a particular Area as the main entry of an MVC4 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

please I need help with this scenario:

I have an Area "\UI" with one Controller "ActionController" and his View "Login.cshtml" also in his UIAreaRegistration class:

```
public class UIAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "UI"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "UI_default",
            "UI/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now I want Login.cshtml to be the first view of the app.
Then in 'RegisterRoutes' of global.asax.cs I have:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

//Default    
//routes.MapRoute(
//    name: "Default",
//    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
//    namespaces: new[] { "", "" },
//    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
//);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area = "UI", controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But didn't work, please what should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to make your UI area a default area, so any controller in UI will be accessible without UI prefix in URL. 
The problem with that is that the controllers which are in root folder will no longer be accessible. If it is what you want you can do it by changing the area route registration from :

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "UI_default",
            "UI/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

to:

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "UI_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Easier solution will be to create an action on the default controller which will redirect user to your area